# iOS : Loading GMSMapView consuming loads of memory and decrease in FPS(Frames Per Second) rate

Tags: ios, google-maps, memory-management, frame-rate, gmsmapview

I have created a google `map` view where I placed some annotations and placing them at the time of loading, but when I change my camera view continuously, memory consumption gets too high about 200MB. FPS rate also lowers down from 30 to 5or6. My app goes nothing but crashing. How can I release that memory ? Here is my code of what I am doing when I move camera angle,

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapview didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position 
{
    [self updateCenterOfScreenMarker:position.target];
}

- (void)updateCenterOfScreenMarker:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
       [self updateMarkers:currentLocation];
    CLLocation * centerOfGreen = [self getLocationCenterOfGreen];
    if (centerOfGreen) {
        CLLocation * currentCamera = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude];
        CLLocationDistance distance = [currentCamera distanceFromLocation:centerOfGreen];
        distanceFromCameraToGolfer = [currentCamera distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];
        [currentCamera release];

        distanceFromCameraToCenterOfGreen = distance;
        if (isYards) {
            distanceFromCameraToCenterOfGreen *= METERS_TO_YARDS;
            distanceFromCameraToGolfer *= METERS_TO_YARDS;
        }

        if (centerMarker) {
            centerMarker.map = nil; // You can remove a marker from the map by setting your GMSMarker's map property to nil.
            [centerMarker release];
            centerMarker = nil;
            headingLabel.text=@"";
            headingLabel=nil;
            headingLabel.text=nil;
            headingLabel2.text=@"";
            headingLabel2=nil;
            headingLabel2.text=nil;
            headingLabel3.text=@"";
            headingLabel3=nil;
            headingLabel3.text=nil;
            headingLabel4.text=@"";
            headingLabel4=nil;
            headingLabel4.text=nil;
            centerMarker.icon =nil;
        }


        if (mapView) {
//            centerMarker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:coordinate];
            headingLabel.text=@"";
            headingLabel2.text=@"";
            headingLabel3.text=@"";
            headingLabel4.text=@"";

            if(distanceFromCameraToGolfer >= 1000)
            {
                headingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 180, 120, 30)];
                headingLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 180, 40, 30)];
                headingLabel3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 180, 20, 30)];
                headingLabel4 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225, 180, 70, 30)];
            }
            else
            {
                headingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 180, 100, 30)];
                headingLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 180, 40, 30)];
                headingLabel3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 180, 20, 30)];
                headingLabel4 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(195, 180, 70, 30)];
            }
            headingLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Bold" size:30];
            headingLabel2.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Regular" size:30];
            headingLabel3.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:30];
            headingLabel4.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Bold" size:30];

            headingLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            headingLabel2.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            headingLabel3.textColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            headingLabel4.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

            headingLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
            headingLabel2.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            headingLabel3.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            headingLabel4.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;


            headingLabel.text=nil;
            headingLabel2.text=nil;
            headingLabel3.text=nil;
            headingLabel4.text=nil;

//            centerMarker.title = nil;
//            centerMarker.snippet = nil;
//            centerMarker.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
            str=@"";
            str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",distanceFromCameraToGolfer];
            str2=@"";

            NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            NSString * units = [defaults objectForKey:PREFERENCE_KEY_UNITS];
            if ([units isEqualToString:@"yards"]) {
                str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Yd"]; 
            }
            else
            {
                str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" m"];
            }

            str3=@"";
            str3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/"];
            str4=@"";
            str4 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", distanceFromCameraToCenterOfGreen];

            if([str4 intValue]>=0 && [str4 intValue]<=14)
            {
                headingLabel.hidden=YES;
                headingLabel2.hidden=YES;
                headingLabel3.hidden=YES;
                headingLabel4.hidden=YES;
            }

            headingLabel.text=str;
            headingLabel2.text=str2;
            headingLabel3.text=str3;
            headingLabel4.text=str4;
            [mapView addSubview:headingLabel];
            [mapView addSubview:headingLabel2];
            [mapView addSubview:headingLabel3];
            [mapView addSubview:headingLabel4];
//            centerMarker.icon = [self addText:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grid.png"] text:@""  red:255 green:255 blue:255];
//            centerMarker.map = mapView;
//            centerMarker.tappable=NO;
            [centerMarker retain];
            [headingLabel release];
            [headingLabel2 release];
            [headingLabel3 release];
            [headingLabel4 release];

        } // mapView

    }

}
```

Here in above code heading labels are the labels that show distance from current location to camera position.
Following is the image of memory consumption and FPS.

[image: Memory Consumption and FPS screenshot]

Comment: This might help you release memory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390581/ios7-memory-release-issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try,
change in this delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position{
    [self updateCenterOfScreenMarker:position.target];
}
```